# Cannot implicitly convert type "System.Linq.IQueryable<string>" An explicit conversion exsits(are you missing a cast?))

Tags: c#, linq

How to select specific item from the list of ParentProductsList? I try this Shows error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists,are you missing a cast?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  AOAPlusViewModel AOAPlusViewModel = new AOAPlusViewModel();

  IQueryable<AoaUserDefinedVWGetAOAPlusProducts> ParentProductLists =               
    AoaSvcClient.Client.Context.AoaUserDefinedVWGetAOAPlusProductss
                               .Where(a => a.MasterProductFlag == true);
  if (bool)
  {
    ParentProductLists = ParentProductLists.Where(p => p.Affiliate == "MN")
                                           .Select(p => p.LongName);   
  }
}
```

Comment: You are selecting the name which is presumably a string. Is this what you intended since you are putting it into a variable of generic type `AoaUserDefinedVWGetAOAPlusProducts`...

Comment: You should put a semi colon after that. Also, change Select FirstOrDefault()

Comment: Yes p.LongName is a string. I am trying to filter the individual ParentProducts  based on the affiliate state and select its p.LongName property.

Comment: if you change the select to a where clause (or include it the condition in the first clause), do you end up with the correct result?  It appears your intention is to replace your IEnumerable with the filtered results, rather than an IEnumerable containing just LongName.  Possibly you want to .First()/.Single() on the resultset also, but your question is extremely unclear and your code snippet is incomplete.

Comment: .Select(p => p.LongName) will transform the collection elements into string. hence it is throwing the exception

Comment: What *exactly* do you want your action method to return?

Answer (score 0):

`ParentProductLists` is of type `IQueryable<AoaUserDefinedVwGetAOAPlusProducts>`. You're code executes a `Select` on `LongName` returning an `IQueryable<string>` that you're trying to assign back to `ParentProductLists` there's no implicit cast between these two types, hence the error. 
Try assigning the return value from the `Select` to a new variable.

Comment: I want to assign the results of my query to my viewmodel for rendering in my view.

Comment: Thank you the example worked as well as gave me a clear understanding of what i was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially it's the same Answer that Andy Lamb already gave but with a Sample Code for clarification.

```
IQueryable<string> LongNameList = ParentProductLists.Where(p => p.Affiliate == "MN")
                                              .Select(p => p.LongName);
```

If you want a Filtered ParentProductLists you have to delete the Select Statement.

```
ParentProductLists = ParentProductLists.Where(p => p.Affiliate == "MN");
```